# Neos Editor - Deleted Nodes reappear after page reload

Tags: neoscms

I created a new Neos Instance, using the [Sandstorm Neos Kickstart](https://github.com/sandstorm/neos-kickstart). After importing the content dump via `./flow site:import my.site` I got some content elements which I deleted using the editor and published my changes. After a page reload I noticed that nodes were their again.

I also noticed that the outline of the elements is orange and not blue, is this the problem? And what does it mean?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orange outline means, that these nodes shine through from another dimension.

Inside the kickstart package there [currently is](https://github.com/sandstorm/neos-kickstart/blob/6873e028a8c1cf70778958694173092c64334404/app/DistributionPackages/Sandstorm.ProjectX/Configuration/Settings.yaml) a (german) content dimension configured. However the [site export](https://github.com/sandstorm/neos-kickstart/blob/6873e028a8c1cf70778958694173092c64334404/app/DistributionPackages/Sandstorm.ProjectX/Resources/Private/Content/Sites.xml#L21) uses nodes without a specific dimension, which leads to nodes shining through from "no dimension" to your dimension.

To fix this you can run `./flow site:prune` and add your content dimension to the site export by replacing the self closing `<dimensions/>` with:

```
<dimensions>
    <language>de</language>
</dimensions>
```

(You would have to do this on every node, of course!)
Afterwards you need to import the site again, to make it all work.

(I assume that this will be fixed inside the kickstart package site export, soon)

Comment: nice, fixed it for me! Thanks a lot :)